# How to keep database active in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are using spring boot, apache camel and multiple datasources.

```
spring boot version: 1.5.9 release
primary database: postgres
Secondary database:oracle
```

We have deployed  spring boot jar in linux server.

Datasource properties for postgres is

```
x.datasource.url=
x.datasource.username=
x.datasource.password=
x.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

datasource properties for oracle

```
y.datasource.url=
y.datasource.username=
y.datasource.password=
y.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

when application keeps ideal and After some times we are trying first request failed and getting error jdbc connection failed but it is working in second request without restarting.

please let me know how to keep database active.

Comment: Try to use Session that will help you.

Comment: can i get some sample code please

Comment: @rasmiranjan - It is a bit unclear as to what you are asking for the in last paragraph of the question. Are you saying that when the application goes idle and comes back, request to PostGres Datasource fails with a jdbc connection failed error but oracle datasource works fine? Also, can I know how you are hosting the db instances and the springboot? Are you using heroku by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hikari connection pool. Refer to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari) on how to implement. You can configure no. of connections you want to keep with db